# Are Repositories implementations part of my domain? Should repositories have SQL queries?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Are Repository implementations part of my domain model or I should make only abstractions of them part of my domain?

And should I put SQL queries on my repositories or they are placed in another pattern and passed as dependency for my repository?

Thanks

**Update**
[image: Illustration]

**Update 2**
Please, take a look at: http://leocavalcante.github.io/patterns/2014/07/11/repository-pattern-and-database-schema.html

Comment: Only the abstraction is part of your domain. You should be able to swap out implementations without breaking your domain. Repository implementations can contain raw SQL, have a dependency on an ORM, whatever really. http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/01/repositories-where-did-we-go-wrong_26.html

Comment: @JefClaes what you think about this? http://yuml.me/1f5c9114

Comment: From the diagrams you posted, it seems that you should have an interface `UserRepository` and two concrete classes implementing it: `SchemaAUserRepository` and `SchemaBUserRepository`.  Then using inversion of control you can inject the appropriate repository into your factory.

Comment: @EdSaito that was early but imagine a scenario where you have only two schemas and besides that you will have different data access layer implementions (ORM engines), I will have 4 repositories for each Entity!!! SchemaAEngineAUserRepository, SchemaBEngineAUserRepository, SchemaAEngineBUserRepository, SchemaBEngineBUserRepository! That sounds weird, what you think?

Comment: I'm not sure how weird it is because we cannot imagine everything.  Try to think of namespaces: If it were Java, you could have `com.acme.infra.jpa.SchemaAUserRepository` and `com.acme.infra.ibatis.SchemaAUserRepository`, and both would implement `com.acme.domain.UserRepository`.  The client tests only have to deal with one repository contract and expect the same behaviour in the end, which is still the most critical aspect you can predict.

Comment: Are these questions driven by a real scenario? I have never changed repository implementations in a real project - except for in-memory ones for testing.

Comment: Please, take a look at: http://leocavalcante.github.io/patterns/2014/07/11/repository-pattern-and-database-schema.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using a hexagon, onion or ports and adapters style architecture, then the normal practice is to put your repository interfaces in your domain model and your repository implementations in your persistence layer/adapter.  You would then wire them up using an IoC container and add a reference from your persistence layer to your domain model.  This allows you to use your domain model entities and value objects in your persistence layer, but also have access to your repositories in your domain model via IoC.

Where you put your SQL is up to you, this isn't particularly a DDD thing, but it probably belongs in your repositories.  Standard practice is to use a stored procedure or a LINQ style query using ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate.  In the later case, the query would exist in the repository.

Good practice is for your repositories to accept domain entities (i.e. for creating/updating) and also return domain entities (i.e. for queries).  Any auto-generated entities generated by an ORM would normally be hidden by your repositories.  This might appear to do-away with a lot of the 'goodness' you get from an ORM (like lazy-loading and 2-way navigation properties), but these things are often a hindrance to good DDD and particularly good object/entity design.

**Extra Detail**

The repository pattern's goal is to 'act like a list' in order to hide persistence details.  So the goal when designing a repository is to make it a simple collection where items can be added, removed and changed.  Behind the scenes, your repository can (should) know about where it is storing the data, i.e. a SQL database, flat files, XML files etc.

In DDD you'd ideally want one repository per aggregate root. For example persisting a single `Customer` aggregate root (an aggregate root may be a single entity, or an entity made up of other entities or value objects) may result in writing to 4 separate tables.

Comment: Is a bad thing my Repository know about my database schema? Because if I implement another database with a different schema, my Repository that knew about a `users` table, now can't handle a `tbl_users` for example. How to avoid that, one Repository implementation per database schema?

Comment: Please, take a look at: http://leocavalcante.github.io/patterns/2014/07/11/repository-pattern-and-database-schema.html

Comment: I'd also mention that "the database might change" is one thing that is very unlikely to change and a lot effort shouldn't be put into anticipating this.  In reality a lot of legacy apps run on their legacy databases until they're eventually retired.  Also if you did change database, it wouldn't violate OCP to make the changes.  All you would need to do is create new repositories and switch over using a setting in your IoC container.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, repository implementations can definitely be a part of your domain model.  In Domain Driven Design, for instance, the main objective when implementing a repository is to focus on the the perspective of the code that consumes the repository, not the code in the repository itself.

In the [Domain Driven Design book](http://www.amazon.ca/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215), pg 155:

> **Implementing a Repository**
>
> Implementation will vary greatly, depending on the technology being
>   used for persistence and the infrastructure you have.  The ideal is
>   to hide all the inner workings from the client (although not from the
>   developer of the client), so that client code will be the same whether
>   the data is stored in a object database, stored in a relational
>   database, or simply held in memory.

Also, yes, you may put SQL queries in a repository implementation.  In a layered architecture, the domain layer is dependent on the infrastructure layer, and SQL is part of the infrastructure layer.  However, when you have a need for transactions, it becomes almost impossible to use the [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern, since the repository implementation should not be responsible for managing transactions -- that should be implemented in a service layer, usually.

If you need transactions in your domain model, most likely you need to use an ORM or a domain specific query language for your repository, so that you can write your SQL queries in an infrastructure layer object which will keep track of which objects need to be persisted within the start and end of a transaction.

Comment: Please, take a look at: http://leocavalcante.github.io/patterns/2014/07/11/repository-pattern-and-database-schema.html